# MySQL Database not Updating when Form Submitted using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, runtime-error

This is a webpage that I have:

```
// Info to connect to the Wishlist database
$servername = "em";
$dbusername = "";
$password = "!19";
$dbname = "";

// To connect to the database please
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);

// If unable to connect to the database display this error
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Connection to wishlist failed";
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

echo "Once you have added creatures to your wishlist, click " .
    "<strong><a href='http://eggcavity.com/edit-wishlist'>here</a></strong> to edit your wishlist.";

// Get current user's username
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$username = $current_user->user_login;

// Retrieve data from the database
$sql = "SELECT Name, Stage1 FROM Creatures";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // Display all of the data from the database
    echo '<form method="POST">';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<div style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">' .
            '<img src="' . $row["Stage1"] . '"><br>'.
            $row["Name"] .
            '<br><input type="checkbox" name="creautres[]" value="' .
            $row["Name"] .
            '"></div>';
    }
    echo '<br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
} else {
    echo "Creatures not found";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['creatures'] as $selected){
        $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $username .
            " (Creature, Picture, Stage, Gender, Frozen, Notes) VALUES ('" .
            $selected . "', 'http://static.eggcave.com/90x90/" . $selected .
            "_1', 'Stage1', 'Unspecified', 'Unspecified', 'Unspecified', '')";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
}

// Close the connection to the database
$conn->close();
```

It displays like I want it to:
[image: Display]
But it doesn't update the database when I click the submit button.

I've tried echoing $stmt, it seemed to be written as it should be.
When I try echoing $selected, within the loop it doesn't seem to output anything.

Can you help me?

---

I have updated the code to use one database. Please help me. It still isn't adding.

Comment: Why does each user have their own specific table? There should be a table of users that has a relationship with another table 'wishlist'.  Can you post your DB schema?  You should also separate the form and the DB logic, for simplicity sake create an add_wishlist.html that posts to a database.php.  <form method='post' action='database.php'>  It'll start making it easier for you to troubleshoot.

Comment: If you got the $username, why then say go to info schema (of all places), and say if tablename is $username, then use tablename? What in the world? Because you want to use info schema to determine if you have already created a user specific table !! Why not have a users table. Have FK's into other shared tables.

Comment: @LeoFNaN and Drew
I appreciate your help but I also have no idea what you guys are saying. I'm new to SQL and creating a table for each user was really the only way I could think to do this.

Comment: Think of what you want to do. Like, eggs for instance. Or Roles or Skills or something. You users can use the same single table for those things by having userId or something. Just look into it or post a schema with `show create table xyz` for each table xyz and people will help

Comment: Thanks @Drew Once I get this all working I will refine it. It's not currently released or anything so once I figure out how to do all of thise I will figure it out. I think I get what you're saying more or less. Have all wishlists in one table and add a column for their username? Then you can run code off of that.

Comment: Yes. And it is our responsibility to point out the way it should be done, not just answer it the way that makes you happy and screws you up shortly thereafter.

Comment: I understand that. But I am doing something wrong with my coding. If I figure out what I am doing wrong switching it over to all one database will be significantly easier. I just need to figure out what I am coding wrong before I can fix it to work that way. Otherwise I'll just be stuck here again but with something I understand less

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118248/discussion-between-turtlebo-and-drew).

Comment: Feel free to pop over to the [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290) chat room. I will take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a typo in your checkbox name. I re-did the submit line in the form and the `isset()` I believe.

The below includes activating error reporting, a try/catch, binding for safety against sql injection. The data saves. You will need to deal with what should be unique data getting saved more than once of course. For instance, a unique key on (Creature,Username). And I would re-think the columns for Id's, but this was your table design. Thanks for allowing us to show you a re-use of a table. Good luck.

schema (from you):

```
drop table if exists Wishlists;
CREATE TABLE `Wishlists` ( 
`ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`Creature` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`Picture` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL, 
`Stage` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`Gender` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`Frozen` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
`Notes` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL, 
`Username` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB; -- <------------------------ went with InnoDB
-- truncate table Wishlists; -- used during early testing
```

PHP (eggs01.php):

```
// Info to connect to the Wishlist database
$servername = "serve it up";
$dbusername = "dbu dbu dbu";
$password = "OpenSesame";
$dbname = "my db name";

try {
    // To connect to the database please
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die('Connect Error (' . $conn->connect_errno . ') '
            . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "I am connected and feel happy.<br/>";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // Postback - submit

        // Get current user's username
        //$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); // remmed out, I don't have your system
        //$username = $current_user->user_login; // remmed out, I don't have your system
        $theCount=0;
        foreach($_POST['creatures'] as $selected){
            $Creature=$selected;
            $Picture="http://static.eggcave.com/90x90/" . $selected . "_1";
            $Stage="Stage1";
            $Gender="Unspecified";
            $Frozen="Unspecified"; 
            $Notes="Unspecified"; 
            $Username="Stackoverflow123";
            $sql = "INSERT Wishlists (Creature, Picture, Stage, Gender, Frozen, Notes, Username) " .
                   " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); // SQL Injection - safe prepare / bind / execute
            // 7 s's means 7 strings:
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssss', $Creature, $Picture, $Stage, $Gender, $Frozen, $Notes, $Username);
            $stmt->execute();
            $theCount++;
        }
        echo "<br>Santa has been notified, count = ".$theCount."<br>";
    }
    else {
        // Just display the form

        // Retrieve data from the database
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT Name, Stage1 FROM Creatures");
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // Display all of the data from the database
            echo '<form method="POST">';
            while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<div style="display: inline-block; width: 30%;">' .
                    '<img src="' . $row["Stage1"] . '"><br>'.
                    $row["Name"] .
                    '<br><input type="checkbox" name="creatures[]" value="' .
                    $row["Name"] .
                    '"></div>';
            }
            echo '<br><br><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></form>';
            $result->close();
        } else {
            echo "Creatures not found";
        }
    }
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) { 
    throw $e; 
}
```

After the submit having selected 3 eggs:

[image]

Database Image:

[image]

Comment: You are a god send. Thank you

Comment: Glad to hear it TurtleBo. Stop on by chat anytime

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look at code

```
$dbname1 = *****";
```

Here you are missing " :
So replace this with

```
$dbname1 = "*****";
```

and try again

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo from when I was editing out the db name. I checked my code to make sure

Answer (score 0):

First issue is you should never run a SQL statement in a Loop ALWAYS AVOID THIS - as it will put your server through a lot of strain.

And 2nd try this and tell me the out put

```
        foreach($_POST['creatures'] as $selected){
        $stmt = "INSERT INTO " . $username . " (Creature, Picture, Stage, Gender, Frozen, Notes) VALUES ('" . $selected . "', 'http://static.eggcave.com/90x90/" . $selected . "_1', 'Stage1', 'Unspecified', 'Unspecified', 'Unspecified', '')";
        if ($conn->query($stmt) === TRUE) {
        }
    }
```

TO

```
    foreach($_POST['creatures'] as $selected){
        $stmt = "INSERT INTO " . $username . " (Creature, Picture, Stage, Gender, Frozen, Notes) VALUES ('" . $selected . "', 'http://static.eggcave.com/90x90/" . $selected . "_1', 'Stage1', 'Unspecified', 'Unspecified', 'Unspecified', '')";
         $result = $conn->query($stmt) OR die(var_dump($conn));    
var_dump($result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC));    
die;

}
```

Comment: We don't need a table per user. Gain points by helping this OP not continuing this nonsense.

Comment: Still not updating ):

Comment: whats the out put you got

Comment: I didn't see any output

Comment: then the problem is way before this part of the script executes search your log files it might point you in the right direction

Comment: I've updated my code to use one database like @Drew wanted. But it still isn't updating. I don't know what the log files are so idk how that will help me.